# Validate gps coordinates lat and long

Tags: c#, regex

I have two regexes took from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119160/2829150
It should correctly validate both latitude and longitude. Nevertheless something is wrong, and for valid coordinates it gives me false.

Example (valid) coordinates which is till got as it is not valid according to methods regex.

```
Lat: 53.0102721
Lon: 18.6048094
```

Code:

```
public static bool IsValidLatitude(string latitude)
{
      var reg = new Regex(@"^(\+|-)?((\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?[0-8]\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?90((\.)|\.0{1,6})?))$");
      return reg.IsMatch(latitude);
}

public static bool IsValidLongitude(string longtitude)
{
      var reg = new Regex(@"^(\+|-)?((\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?\d\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?1[0-7]\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?180((\.)|\.0{1,6})?))$");
      return reg.IsMatch(longtitude);
}
```

**Note that:** it don't need to be regex. It can be whatever else keeping in mind to check whether dot (.) was used no matter to what pc settings for separator is set up. I am open on any other proposition.

Comment: `d{1,6}` matches 1-6 digits and `53.0102721` has 7 digits after the dot.

Comment: @Thefourthbird so means regex is not correct or?

Comment: Much easier instead of complicated regex: use `decimal.TryParse` to parse the string, and verify the result is between -90 and 90 or -180 and 180.

Comment: Why are you using Regex and not a numeric type?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay don;t know i am not regex expert just took it from original post

Comment: @jeroenh Can you post proposition as full answer. Keeping in mind i have to save it in database with dot (.) not any other related to pc settings but according what i do know decimal.TryParse will pass system separator. In this case regex is better it guaranty dot (.) is used.

Comment: @Arie The pattern tries several alternatives and matches 1-6 digits and your example data has 7 digits after the dot. I can not say that the pattern by itself is not correct, but it does not match your data. I think the other suggestions in the comment would be an easier approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be simpler to parse to double then validate:

```
public static bool IsValidLatitude(string latitude)
    => double.TryParse(latitude, out var l) && -90 <= l && l <= 90;

public static bool IsValidLongitude(string longitude)
    => double.TryParse(longitude, out var l) && -180 <= l && l <= 180;
```

---

To force `.` as the decimal separator, you could use an overload of `double.TryParse` that allows `CultureInfo.InvariantCultute` to be used:

```
public static bool IsValidLatitude(string latitude)
    => double.TryParse(latitude, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCultute, out var l)
        && -90 <= l && l <= 90;

public static bool IsValidLongitude(string longitude)
    => double.TryParse(longitude, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCultute, out var l)
        && -180 <= l && l <= 180;
```

Comment: Can you modify to make sure (.) dot is used ?

Comment: `double` is a floating-point type, so includes decimal places.

Comment: Yes, what i ment is : if user's pc decimal separator is set to e.g comma (,) i don't want such coordinate to be treated as valid.

Comment: Would it mean if any other separator than dot (.) comes into your methods even if coordinates are valid it will return false ?

Comment: Yes, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` sets the [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator) to `.`, so only `.` is a valid separator.

Comment: I thoughtdiffrent that the option: CultureInfo.InvariantCultute will make a check nevermind to user's culture, means if user either has dot or comma in system as decimal separator that function will work, but without that option (CultureInfo.InvariantCultute) if user type separator that is <> system settings method will not work (get false.

Comment: Not so: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2t9Bkk

Comment: [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture): "_The invariant culture is culture-insensitive_".

Comment: ok so simply saying doesn't matter what pc settings are set for decimal separator. In this way means with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture those methods will return true only when coordinate is valid and separator is dot (.) ?

Comment: @Arie Yes, the only thing to note is that `NumberStyles.Float` allows trailing and leading whitespace, which may or may not be a problem. If it is, replace that with `NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint`.

Comment: you mean if values comes to args of methods with leading/trainiling spaces? If so we just could make Trim on incomming arguments values as well? Or its better as you said to replace NumberStyles.Float to NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint ?

Comment: `NumberStyles.Float` will trim anyway. If this is not valid, use `NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint`.

Answer (score 2):

A much easier way to validate coordinates is to parse the string to a numeric value, and verify it is between -90 and 90 (latitude) and -180 and 180 (longitude):

```
string latitudeString = "53.0102721";
string longitudeString = "18.6048094";

        bool latitudeIsValid = decimal.TryParse(latitudeString, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint|NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var latitude) 
                              && Math.Abs(latitude) < 90);
        bool longitudeIsValid = decimal.TryParse(longitudeString, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint|NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var longitude) 
                              && Math.Abs(longitude) < 180);
```

As per your requirement to save as a string using `.` as a decimal separator: first, I would advise to use a numeric data type in your storage system (if possible). If you must store as a string, you can use the original string, or use `decimal.ToString` with a correct culture and format specifier:

```
string latitudeAsString = latitude.ToString("N7", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Can you modify to make sure (.) dot is used ?

Comment: Why are you storing this data as a string? Better to use a decimal or floating point type. The decimal separator is just a representation.

Comment: can youn tell me whats N7?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966430/format-a-number-with-x-decimal-places-and-invariantculture

Comment: So it means your code will change delimeter to dot(.) if any other delimeter will be returned according to user's settings or it will keep dot(.) if its already there, am i right?

Comment: @Arie, this is going to a totally different question. You will find a whole lot more information elsewhere, for example in the documentation on formatting of types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types

Comment: P.S YOu fot error in your code at Math.Abs(longitude) cannot convert from string to decimal. P.S Why decimal and not double?

Comment: decimal has greater precision, but double would also work fine for this case

Comment: at this line i get: latitude.ToString("N7", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments

Comment: `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` doesn't allow negative numbers.